# Setting value of Django field inside of Form class

Tags: django

I'm trying to set the value of a Django field inside of the Form class. Here is my model

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User , db_column='userid')

    datesubmitted = models.DateField() 
    workoutdate = models.DateField(); 
    bodyweight = models.FloatField(null=True);
    workoutname = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Here is the form class, in which i am attempting to achieve this:

```
class WorkoutForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta: 
        model = Workout

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        # this is obviously wrong, I don't know what variable to set self.data to
        self.datesubmitted = self.data['datesubmitted']
```

Ok, sorry guys. I'm passing the `request.POST` data to the `WorkoutForm` in my view like this

```
w = WorkoutForm(request.POST)
```

However, unfortunately the names of the html elements have different names then the names of the model. For instance, there is no `date submitted` field in the html. This is effectively a time stamp that is produced and saved in the database.

So I need to be able to save it inside the form class some how, I think.

That is why I am trying to set the `datesubmitted` field to `datetime.datetime.now()`

Basically I am using the form class to make the verification easier, and I AM NOT using the form for it's html output, which I completely disregard.

Comment: So... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to get the posted data?

Comment: I added more information

Comment: Your form is a `ModelForm` the how the html elements have different names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do that in the `save` method of your form

```
class WorkoutForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta: 
        model = Workout

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkoutForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        instance = super(WorkoutForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.datesubmitted = datetime.now()
        instance.save()
```

How ever you can set that in your model also to save the current datetime when ever a new object is created:

```
datesubmitted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You can set some extra values set in form as:

```
form = WorkOutForm(curr_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(), request.POST) # passing datetime as a keyword argument
```

then in form get and set it:

```
def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
    self.curr_datetime = kwargs.pop('curr_datetime')
    super(WorkoutForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Now what about for other arbitrary values in arbitrary Forms, I would have to validate all of this data before I call the save method correct? Would I have to completely re-define the is_valid() method to accompany these arbitrary values being assigned to an arbitrary form?

Comment: the model is going to validate the fields it self. e.g. if you have a field `A` and it is a required field the form will raise `ValidationError` if you left it empty

Comment: is there any way i can assign that value globally, for instance in the __init__ method? will datesubmitted = self.data['datesubmitted'] do the trick?

Comment: Isn't that how you are suppose to access the request.POST data passed to the Form?

Comment: I have updated the answer check at the end. you should get the data after it is validated using `self.cleaned_data`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using a `ModelForm` for this. Use a normal `Form`, and either in the view or in a method create a new model instance, copy the values, and return the model instance.

Comment: Why is this? I'm closely tied with a Model, so then I thought I was suppose to use a ModelForm

Comment: A `ModelForm` takes the field names from the model. Since this is not what you want, you should not be using one.